# Creating bean PropertyDescriptor using JRuby

Tags: jruby

I'm trying to port some java to jruby, and it uses a beans PropertyDescriptor. The original code is:

```
new PropertyDescriptor("splitEvaluator", CrossValidationResultProducer.class)
```

which I've tried to port to:

```
PropertyDescriptor.new("splitEvaluator", CrossValidationResultProducer)
```

However, I get the error:

```
no constructor with arguments matching [class org.jruby.RubyString, class org.jruby.RubyClass] on object #<Java::JavaBeans::PropertyDescriptor:0x86f847> (NameError)
```

The [PropertyDescriptor API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) says the second argument should be a Java Class. What do I need to pass for this to work in JRuby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see an argument that it's a bug that it doesn't work the way you originally expected. Or at least that JRuby would be smart enough to convert a Ruby class representation of a Java class to a Java class argument.

As it is, using #java_class works, as you found out.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. It would be interesting to know if there are any downsides to automatically converting to a Java class if the method expects one.

Answer (score 0):

I need to use the Java class, rather than the Ruby representation of the Java class. This works.

```
PropertyDescriptor.new("splitEvaluator", CrossValidationResultProducer.java_class)
```